# Unable to run Node.js app on MAMP/NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, mamp

I have a Node.js app (my first, so I'm a little inexperienced in this regard) that I'm trying to run locally via MAMP with NGINX, but I'm getting a "403 Forbidden" error (I'm not using Apache as the app's .conf file was written for NGINX).

What I'm unsure about is how to put the app's .conf file into effect. Currently, it's in /env-setup/nginx-setup/, but I'm not sure if it's being executed, or if I have to inser it into /Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf. Also, when I `ls -l` the app folder, I get drwxr-xr-x.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Node.js runs in its own process, not as a CGI or whatever for another server. Node.js needs to setup it's own server. Or are you trying to *proxy* to a node app through nginx?

Comment: @user866762 No, I'm trying to set it up entirely locally. Hmm does that mean it doesn't rely on another server, such as MAMP to run? I'm also confused about that part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to peruse [this guide](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs) starting on or around the heading *Doing Something Useful - HTTP Server* and/or [this guide](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#a-full-blown-web-application-with-nodejs) starting at where that link takes you.

Short story, that's correct, nodejs doesn't rely on another server like php does. It runs in its own process, and is responsible for managing incoming connections and listening for them.

Comment: Thanks, but I discovered that I *do* need NGINX for the app's assets redirects. Still trying to resolve the `403 Forbidden` issue.